# Upgrade Nuget Gallery - EF AutomiaticMigration issue

Tags: entity-framework, powershell, nuget

I self-host nuget gallery inside my company. I am trying to upgrade it but I have following error:

```
Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. 
Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. 
Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.
```

I don't know how can I upgrade my database from powershell/cmd on server. I don't have a VisualStudio installed there.

**UPDATE**

I tried to run manually migrate.exe from EF but I have:

```
ERROR: Could not load file or assembly 'F:\\NugetGallery\\bin\\NuGetGallery.Website' or one of
 its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
```

Comment: Did you see this blog about how to fix this issue? Seems to be quite related: http://robertgreiner.com/2012/05/unable-to-update-database-to-match-the-current-model-pending-changes/ basically they are recommending issuing a `Add-Migration` command to upload any pending changes to the new database.

Comment: @MickyBalladelli I see this but `Add-Migration` requires package manager console from Visual Studio, which I don't have on server